Chrome doesn't load ESM scripts (type="module") on first start after switching machine off, sometimes
I'm aware that ESM can't be loaded until you serve your HTML properly. But I have website which works fine, and only sometimes when I switch my mac off, then after starting browser I see following error in Chrome 127.0.6533.100:
"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."
Website is hosted on "x.cloudfront.net" scripts have correct mime-type server response header, also SSL certificate is correct and not self-signed (which might impact ESM loading as well). This is Angular 17 SPA, with default build settings (not ejected webpack config)
Sometimes Chrome still doesn't load scripts, as if website is loaded from filesystem (cache)
